# Splitting a column but removing everything before colon first

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which is a long string that could look like this called "feature":

```
0:0.084556 1:0.138594 2:0.094304 3:0.195764
```

I want to split it out to individual columns, so for this example it would split to 4 columns. However I want to remove everything before the colon and also the colon as well. So each column would only have the float number.

How would I do this in pandas?

I tried this:

```
train = train.join(train['features'].str.split(' ',expand = True).add_prefix('feature'))
```

but this implementation doesn't remove everything before the colon/the colon

Answer (score 1):

Does this suffice?:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['0:0.084556 1:0.138594 2:0.094304 3:0.195764']})

df.feature.str.replace('\d:','').str.split(expand=True)

        0           1           2           3
0   0.084556    0.138594    0.094304    0.195764
```